# Can Spring Data REST's QueryDSL integration integrate with the existing pagination features?

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest, querydsl

I'm currently building a REST API in which I want clients to easily filter on most properties of a specific entity. Using [QueryDSL](http://querydsl.com/) in combination with [Spring Data REST](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-rest/) ([an example by Oliver Gierke](https://gist.github.com/olivergierke/decf03d4948cd58a51bc)) allows me to easily get to 90% of what I want by allowing clients to filter by combining query parameters which refer to properties (e.g. `/users?firstName=Dennis&lastName=Laumen`). ([If you're using the same integration Oliver Gierke's answer to my previous question might also help.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35155824/can-spring-data-rests-querydsl-integration-be-used-to-perform-more-complex-quer/35158320))

Unfortunately, when using the additional filters QueryDSL provides, like `firstName=Dennis&lastName=Laumen`, these do not seem to integrate with the pagination features of Spring Data REST. The pagination links when `GET`ting a collection resource return links which ignore the applied filters (e.g. `http://localhost:8080/api/users?page=1&size=20` instead of `http://localhost:8080/api/users?page=1&size=20&firstName=Dennis&lastName=Laumen`).

Concluding, is it possible to display the correct pagination links when using Spring Data REST and QueryDSL? If so, how?

Comment: That sounds like a bug. Would you mind opening a ticket in our JIRA?

Comment: Hi @OliverGierke, no problem, will do that this afternoon. Thanks for answering so quickly.

Comment: The bug @OliverGierke referred to in his comment [has been logged here](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-762).

Answer (score -1):

Yes, my spring data widget repository

```
extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Widget, String>,QueryDslPredicateExecutor<Widget>,QuerydslBinderCustomizer<QWidget>
```

and I'm able to use both querydsl and page\size parameters in my http request simulatenously, e.g,

http://localhost:8080/widgets?securityType=XXX&settlementPriceCurrency=ABC&size=16

, and get valid pagination links back:

```
  "_links" : {
    "first" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/widgets?page=0&size=16"
    },
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/widgets{&sort,projection}",
      "templated" : true
    },
    "next" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/widgets?page=1&size=16"
    },
    "last" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/widgets?page=61&size=16"
    },
    "profile" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/profile/widgets"
    }
  },
  "page" : {
    "size" : 16,
    "totalElements" : 984,
    "totalPages" : 62,
    "number" : 0
  }
```

using Spring Data Rest 2.6.6.RELEASE  and spring data commons 1.13.6

Comment: This is quite the opposite of what the Op stated. The links generated by Spring Data REST absolutely do NOT have the original query filters (securityType and settlementPriceCurrency).