# Spring Data REST's QueryDSL integration for querying subproperties of collection mapping in an entity

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest, querydsl

Took some major digging to figure out that spring-data-rest with query-dsl lets REST API clients to easily filter on most properties of an entity.

This question was also useful:
[Can Spring Data REST's QueryDSL integration be used to perform more complex queries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35155824/can-spring-data-rests-querydsl-integration-be-used-to-perform-more-complex-quer)

As Dennis Laumen already mentioned, `QueryDslPredicateExecutor` and `QuerydslBinderCustomizer` provide some spectacular features but lack documentation.

The specific feature I'm trying to crack is:

I have a User entity with @ManyToMany mapping to UserGroup entity

```
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "user_name")
    private String username;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "fs_user_group_map", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "group_id") })
    private List<UserGroup> userGroups;
}
```

I'm trying to fetch all users one of their userGroup's name should match a text:

So the URI I'm trying to hit is: `/users?userGroups.name=Admin`

But this errors out.

```
19:08:04.423|ERROR|o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestExceptionHandler|null
    java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getField(ReflectionUtils.java:143) ~[spring-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.querydsl.binding.QuerydslPredicateBuilder.reifyPath(QuerydslPredicateBuilder.java:185) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.querydsl.binding.QuerydslPredicateBuilder.reifyPath(QuerydslPredicateBuilder.java:188) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.querydsl.binding.QuerydslPredicateBuilder.getPath(QuerydslPredicateBuilder.java:167) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.querydsl.binding.QuerydslPredicateBuilder.invokeBinding(QuerydslPredicateBuilder.java:136) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.querydsl.binding.QuerydslPredicateBuilder.getPredicate(QuerydslPredicateBuilder.java:111) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.QuerydslAwareRootResourceInformationHandlerMethodArgumentResolver.postProcess(QuerydslAwareRootResourceInformationHandlerMethodArgumentResolver.java:91) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-2.4.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RootResourceInformationHandlerMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(RootResourceInformationHandlerMethodArgumentResolver.java:92) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-2.4.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RootResourceInformationHandlerMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(RootResourceInformationHandlerMethodArgumentResolver.java:40) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-2.4.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:78) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:162) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:129) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:814) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:737) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:969) [spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:860) [spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687) [javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:845) [spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) [javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:812) [jetty-servlet-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
```

Some debugging around QuerydslPredicateBuilder.reifyPath led me to understand that userGroups is a `ListPath` and there is an attempt to use reflection to find the property 'name' on it. But the query-dsl path I would actually need is `user.userGroups.any().name`

Trying any other syntax on the URL though doesn't seem to be recognized as valid `PropertyPath` in `QuerydslPredicateBuilder.getPredicate`.

Is this a bug?

Comment: any update on this?

Comment: nop, I was hoping for someone from the spring-data team to clarify

Comment: I guess we might have to contribute here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa

Comment: It appears it is a bug - https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-694

Comment: I don't think that bug truly captures the issue that I mentioned, but the solution to that bug can help. I've up-voted it :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, upgrading to spring-data Ingalls-SR7 fixed this issue.