# Spring @QuerydslPredicate Questions

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, querydsl

### Libaries Used

Spring Boot 1.3.2.RELEASE

QueryDSL 3.7.2

QueryDSL Maven Plugin 1.1.3

Hibernate 4.3.11.Final

### Issue

Currently, I have a Spring Boot application that has some basic CRUD functionality using Spring Data JPA (backed by Hibernate), and auditing using Spring Data Envers. I also have the following endpoint to retrieve a list of entities from:

> http://localhost:8080/test-app/list

Now, I wanted to use the [new QueryDSL support that Spring offers](https://spring.io/blog/2015/09/04/what-s-new-in-spring-data-release-gosling#querydsl-web-support) through the `@QuerydslPredicate` annotation. This works fine for most fields or sub-entities, but it doesn't appear to work for collections of sub-entities. The documentation, blog posts, etc. don't seem to cover this case - and the only information I could find is that it supports "in" for simple collections (i.e. collections of String, etc.).

So, my entity is set up something like so:

**Person.java**

```
@Data
@Entity
@Audited
public class Person {

    @Id
    private long id;

    private String name;

    private List<Pet> pets = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

**Pet.java**

```
@Data
@Entity
@Audited
public class Pet {

    @Id
    private long id;

    private int age;

}
```

I generate my Q classes using the `com.mysema.maven:apt-maven-plugin`, which generates my `QPerson` with the following field:

```
public final ListPath<com.test.Pet, com.test.QPet> pets = this.<com.test.Pet, com.test.QPet>createList("pets", com.test.Pet.class, com.test.QPet.class, PathInits.DIRECT2);
```

If I try to query on this though, I get an exception:

**Query:**

> http://localhost:8080/test-app/list?pets.age=5

**Exception:**

```
10:21:37,523 ERROR [org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-1) Forwarding to error page from request [/list] due to exception [null]: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getField(ReflectionUtils.java:143) [spring-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.querydsl.binding.QuerydslPredicateBuilder.reifyPath(QuerydslPredicateBuilder.java:185) [spring-data-commons-1.11.2.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.data.querydsl.binding.QuerydslPredicateBuilder.reifyPath(QuerydslPredicateBuilder.java:188) [spring-data-commons-1.11.2.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.data.querydsl.binding.QuerydslPredicateBuilder.getPath(QuerydslPredicateBuilder.java:167) [spring-data-commons-1.11.2.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.data.querydsl.binding.QuerydslPredicateBuilder.invokeBinding(QuerydslPredicateBuilder.java:136) [spring-data-commons-1.11.2.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.data.querydsl.binding.QuerydslPredicateBuilder.getPredicate(QuerydslPredicateBuilder.java:111) [spring-data-commons-1.11.2.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.data.web.querydsl.QuerydslPredicateArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(QuerydslPredicateArgumentResolver.java:106) [spring-data-commons-1.11.2.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.data.web.querydsl.QuerydslPredicateArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(QuerydslPredicateArgumentResolver.java:48) [spring-data-commons-1.11.2.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:78) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
```

Now this query look like it's trying to resolve the propertyPath `Person.pets.age`. It correctly identifies `Person.pets` as a `ListPath`, and then tries to identify `CompanyAddress.addressLine1` (which seems correct). The problem is, it tries to use the entity path to get the class, which is the `ListPath` instead of the `QPet`:

```
Field field = ReflectionUtils.findField(entityPath.getClass(), path.getSegment());
Object value = ReflectionUtils.getField(field, entityPath);
```

The following query works as expected:

> http://localhost:8080/test-app/list?name=Bob

My expectation was that by using `?pets.age=5`, the following predicate would be built:

```
QPerson.person.pets.any().age.eq(5)
```

Is this currently possible with Spring's QuerydslPredicate support? Or should I manually build the predicates from the query parameters?

### Additional Question

As an additional question, is the following possible with QuerydslPredicate. Say I have a firstName and lastName on pet, and I want to run a query with just `name=Bob`:

> http://localhost:8080/test-app/pet/list?name=Bob

I would want the query predicate to be built like this:

```
final BooleanBuilder petBuilder = new BooleanBuilder();
petBuilder.and(QPet.firstName.equals("Bob").or(QPet.lastName.equals("Bob")));
```

Is that possible? From looking at the customize method of the `QuerydslBinderCustomizer` it doesn't seem like it would be, since you need to bind off a field of the Q class. I'm guessing that what I want to do is not supported.

If these aren't possible, then I'll stick with manually creating the predicate, and passing that on to the repository.

Comment: I too found the documentation on this wanting. Especially exactly how to take advantage of the "in" functionality - http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/reference/html/#core.web.type-safe

Comment: I did find this answer, which does explain at least how to get "in" working if you want to provide multiple matches for a given field - http://stackoverflow.com/a/35158320/228369

Answer (score 2):

You can use `QuerydslBinderCustomizer` to achieve your purpose. Heres some sample code that can help you out:

```
public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Job, Integer>,
        QueryDslPredicateExecutor<Person>, QuerydslBinderCustomizer<QJob> {

    @Override
    public default void customize(final QuerydslBindings bindings, final QPerson person)     {
        bindings.bind(person.pets.any().name).first((path, value) -> {
            return path.eq(value);
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same error. However I noticed that using the QuerydslAnnotationProcessor plugin (instead of the JPA annotation processor) allows me to query sub collections of entities as expected. You just have to mark all of your entity classes with the @QueryEntity annotation. (The JPA annotation processor automatically generates query classes for @Entity annotated classes.)

In your pom:

```
          <plugin>
                <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>process</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/annotations</outputDirectory>
                            <processor>com.querydsl.apt.QuerydslAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
                        <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
                        <version>4.1.3</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
```

I'm believe I was running into the exception you encountered because I changed from the JPA Annotation Processor to the QuerydslAnnotationProcessor, for some reason I do not recall, and neglected to mark the entity class of the list in question with the @QueryEntity annotation. However I also believe I have another Spring-Data-Rest\JPA backed API that uses the JPA Annotation Processor built in August 2017, and I believe querying sub collections of entities works as expected. I'll be able to confirm that later today, and provide the versions of the relevant dependencies if that is the case. Perhaps this issue has been fixed.

Comment: Thanks for the post. I'm not on that specific project any more, so I can't verify it immediately, but I'll try to set up a small project over the next few days and see if that sorts the problem.