# Creating multiple aliases for the same QueryDSL path in Spring Data

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-rest, querydsl

I have a generic Spring Data repository interface that extends `QuerydslBinderCustomizer`, allowing me to customize the query execution.  I am trying to extend the basic equality testing built into the default repository implementation, so that I can perform other query operations using Spring Data REST.  For example:

```
GET /api/persons?name=Joe%20Smith  // This works by default
GET /api/persons?nameEndsWith=Smith  // This requires custom parameter binding.
```

The problem I am having is that every alias of an entity path I create seems to override the preceding alias bindings.

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface BaseRepository<T, ID extends Serializable>
    extends PagingAndSortingRepository<T, ID>, QueryDslPredicateExecutor<T>, QuerydslBinderCustomizer { 

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    default void customize(QuerydslBindings bindings, EntityPath entityPath){

        Class<T> model = entityPath.getType();
        Path<T> root = entityPath.getRoot();
        for (Field field: model.getDeclaredFields()){
            if (field.isSynthetic()) continue;
            Class<?> fieldType = field.getType();
            if (fieldType.isAssignableFrom(String.class)){
                // This binding works by itself, but not after the next one is added
                bindings.bind(Expressions.stringPath(root, field.getName()))
                        .as(field.getName()  + "EndsWith")
                        .first((path, value) -> {
                            return path.endsWith(value);
                        });
                // This binding overrides the previous one
                bindings.bind(Expressions.stringPath(root, field.getName()))
                        .as(field.getName()  + "StartsWith")
                        .first((path, value) -> {
                            return path.startsWith(value);
                        });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is it possible to create more than one alias for the same field?  Can this be accomplished in a generic way?

Comment: Digging through the source it seems that the bindings  are stored in a Map keyed by path: `private final Map<String, PathAndBinding<?, ?>> pathSpecs` which would explain why `bindings.bind(Expressions.stringPath(root, field.getName()))` overrides the previous binding. Don't know if there is another way to achieve this however.

Comment: Check this other answer about a somewhat similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43852346/5747715 Basically you need to create more fields (that are not persisted) to attach functionality to them.

Comment: Is there an easy way to do this now? Limitations like this makes it difficult to use querydsl

Comment: Looks like you are trying to provide generic search api. If so, check rsql parser and rsql-jpa.

Comment: @Adi: What I eventually implemented is a lot like RSQL.  Would be nice if Spring Data and QueryDSL was more flexible in this regard.

Comment: @woemler to turn the tables on this, looks like it could used some operators like `/search/users?emails.value=endsWith(@company.com)&emails.value=endsWith(@legacycompany.com)` there is a project providing those: https://gt-tech.bitbucket.io/spring-data-querydsl-value-operators/README.html

Answer (score 1):

You can create a transient property bound to QueryDSL this way:

```
@Transient
@QueryType(PropertyType.SIMPLE)
public String getNameEndsWith() {
    // Whatever code, even return null
}
```

If you are using the QueryDSL annotation processor, you will see the "nameEndsWith" in the metadata Qxxx class, so you can bind it like any persisted property, but without persisting it.