# Multiple aliases with QuerydslBinderCustomizer

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, querydsl, spring-restcontroller

I'm using QuerydslPredicate in my RestController on an entity which has a date object, I want to be able to query for a date before/after/between given dates, hoping to have something like

- GET /problems?createdOnAfter=XXX
- GET /problems?createdOnBefore=YYY
- GET /problems?createdOnAfter=XXX&createdOnBefore=YYY

My entity has the date field ***createdOn*** and I was hoping I could customise bindings for an entity path using multiple aliases i.e. adding aliases ***createdOnAfter*** & ***createdOnBefore*** - it doesn't look like I can create multiple aliases though, e.g.

```
@Repository
public interface ProblemRepository extends JpaRepository<Problem, String>, QueryDslPredicateExecutor<Problem>,
        QuerydslBinderCustomizer<QProblem> {

            ....

    @Override
    default void customize(QuerydslBindings bindings, QProblem root) {
        bindings.bind(root.createdOn).as("createdOnAfter").first(TemporalExpression::after);
        bindings.bind(root.createdOn).as("createdOnBefore").first(TemporalExpression::before);
    }
}
```

The before alias is obviously overwriting the after one.

What's the correct approach to avoid having to manually create the predicates?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/35158320/5380322 ...

Comment: I was hoping to be able to use createdOnAfter, createdOnBefore or both -  that solution means I have to supply 2 dates everytime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not using QueryDSL Predicate ? You could do :

```
@GetMapping("/problems")
@Timed
public ResponseEntity<List<ProblemDTO>> getAllProblems(
      @RequestParam(required = false) LocalDateTime createdOnAfter, 
      @RequestParam(required = false) LocalDateTime createdOnBefore,
      @ApiParam Pageable pageable) {
    BooleanBuilder where = new BooleanBuilder();
    if (startDate != null) {
        where = where.and(problem.createdOn.after(createdOnAfter));
    }
    if (endDate != null) {
        where = where.and(problem.createdOn.before(createdOnBefore));
    }
    Page<Donnee> page = problemRepository.findAll(where, pageable);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(problemMapper.toDTO(page.getContent())), null, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Hope it helps,
Regards

Comment: Well, it surely helps, if you have limited number of options. But this is not an aswer but a workaround. Is there a correct way to specify multiple "aliases" or "predicated" per single field?

Answer (score 0):

How about adding new Entity properties and marking those as transient like this:

```
@Transient
private Instant createdOnBefore;
@Transient
private Instant createdOnAfter;
```

and then customise your repository class like this:

```
@Override
default void customize(final QuerydslBindings bindings, final QProblem  root) {
    bindings.bind(root.createdOnBefore).first((path, value) -> root.createdOn.goe(value));
    bindings.bind(root.createdOnAfter).first((path, value) -> root.createdOn.loe(value));
}
```