# How to access cross-field values in QueryDSL QuerydslBinderCustomizer?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

How can I access other query parameter values inside `QuerydslBinderCustomizer`?

My goal is to create a `departure.between(min, max)` binding, that I want to derive from two query params `min` and `max`.

Problem is that the `route.max` value is not accessible inside the `customize()` method, or at least I don't know how to access it.

```
/departures?min=2021-01-01&max=2021-01-30

@Repository
public interface RouteRepository extends JpaRepository<Route, Long>, 
     QueryDslPredicateExecutor<QRoute>, QuerydslBinderCustomizer<QRoute> {

  @Override
  default public void customize(QuerydslBindings bindings, QRoute route) {
     //value is the 'min' query parameter. HOW can I access the 'max' parameter here??
     bindings.bind(route.min).first((path, value) -> route.departure.between(value, route.max));
  }
}

@Entity
class Route {
      @Id long id;
      @Transient LocalDate min, max; //only for the query
      LocalDate departure; //real db field
}
```

Comment: in route 'min' you can do route.departure.after(value), in route 'max' route.departure.before(value), so you get departure > min && departure < max

Comment: In this specific case - yes. But it's just an example, and the question targets "cross field references" in general.

Answer (score -1):

It should be that Querydsl cannot generate a Q object. I am looking for a similar method. You can refer to this[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35155824/can-spring-data-rests-querydsl-integration-be-used-to-perform-more-complex-quer/35158320#35158320)

Comment: Your answer suits best in the comment section.